# Helmholtz decomposition - motivation

Tags: soft-question, physics, vector-analysis

Our lecturer presented us the Helmholtz decomposition of smooth vector fields. He added a proof, but he didn't provide any single motivation - e.g. where Helmholtz used the decomposition or for which reasons is it mainly employed. Could anyone mention some  motivation?

Answer (score 2):

Physicist-to-be here!

Helmholtz's decomposition thm is useful when dealing with electromagnetism: with the notation of the wpedia page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition), when F is either the electric or magnetic field, you can employ Maxwell's Laws to find the formulas for the computing of electric/magnetic potentials.

Comment: Thanks, so the basic is to recover potentials as parts of field? It was said on the lecture that this theorem is very important in mathematics. When the lecturer was not able to answer why, I decided to ask here :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you decomposed F = nabla X A + nabla.phi

Then,

```
nabla.F = nabla.nable.phi
nabla X F = nabla X nabla X A
```

If you integrate F, you only have to integrate nabla X A, because the nabla.phi part can be simplified using the chain rule into phi(endposition)-phi(startposition).
integrating nabla X A can usually be simplified using stoke's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

One motivation would be to find different kind of wave motion in solids.

For an isotropic solid we have the following equations

$$\rho \frac{\partial^2 \mathbf{u}}{\partial t^2} = (\lambda + 2\mu) \nabla\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} - \mu \nabla \times \nabla \times \mathbf{u} \enspace ,$$

using Helmholtz decompositions you can "translate" these equations into the following wave equations

$$\nabla^2 \phi = \frac{1}{\alpha^2} \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2}$$

and

$$\nabla^2 \mathbf{A} = \frac{1}{\beta^2} \frac{\partial^2 \mathbf{A}}{\partial t^2}\, ,$$

where $\alpha$ is the speed of longitudinal waves (P-waves) and $\beta$ is the speed of transverse wave (S-waves).